# Dynamically build ApplicationContext from code/get dependencies

Tags: java, spring, reflection

i am working on a really big enterprise application, with couple of thousand beans, and a big dependency graph between classes. We are using Spring 3, with @Autowired fields (autowiring in constuctor).

I am trying to create an integration test for one of the controllers, which has multiple dependencies, each of those with more dependencies, etc. It is borderline impossible to create an xml definition of the classes which needs to be resolved because of the bad project structure and dependency graph - therefore i cant build the ApplicationContext...

What i am trying to do is to scan for fields in a class, and if they are beans (Component, Service, etc), add them to the ApplicationContext from the code.

I could iterate through the class' fields in a recursive function with relfection i guess, and add the beans to the appcontext, but i have no idea how...

How can i do this? Is this feasible?

Comment: how about constructing application context with bean's lazy initialization ?

Comment: What do you mean? Please add some details :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, you're trying to solve the wrong problem. If your module structure is in that state, trying to build the context dynamically is not going to help you because ultimately you're going to load pretty much the whole application.

I would advise you to create a common "low-level" stack for your app: something that is reasonable and clearly identified by separate modules. Once you have that, start creating boundaries for major features and try to load only them.

If you can't do that, you can still load a test application context by using mocks to cut dependencies in your graph. In any case, discovering the fields to wire along the way is not going to buy you anything.

Comment: You are absolutely right. That is the solution we have suggested, and it has been rejected, because of the amount of the work that needs to be done in order to achieve this...

Using mocks: yeah, that's what we have used so far, and this is just an exploratory work to see if "real code" can be used in int. tests or not...